# Open unsupported file type extensions with uwp app

Tags: wpf, uwp, desktop-bridge

[This](https://github.com/JasonStein/Notepads/pull/534) is a PR for an uwp text editor app where I am implementing desktop extension to give user choice of opening file for which association not declared in manifest. User can choose to open the file with the extension which then launches the file with the uwp app. However I am having following issues:

1. The `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync()` doesn't work for hidden files. Trying to handle file activation using [this](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2019/05/10/handle-protocol-activation-and-redirection-in-packaged-apps/) article gives following error:

   > System.Exception HResult=0xD0000225 Message=The text associated with
   >   this error code could not be found.
   >
   > The text associated with this error code could not be found.
   >
   > Source=Windows.ApplicationModel StackTrace: at
   >   Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInstance.GetActivatedEventArgs()
2. Also launching with `Launcher.LaunchFileAsync()` doesn't work for unsupported extensions.

Any help regarding these issues??

Comment: I check above PR, but it does not contain desktop extension part, how do you implement the extension?

Comment: It does, the project name for desktop extension is Notepads.DesktopExtension. Go here: https://github.com/soumyamahunt/Notepads/tree/desktop-extension-registry/src

Comment: So you call launch api to launch  the uwp app with file within desktop extension, right?

Comment: Yes, but the launch only succeeds for file types that are already supported. For other file types nothing happens, no exception either. Just the execution stops at that line.

Comment: For my opinion, it's by design, why do you want to make your app support all file type?

Comment: Since it is a text editor app I want it to support all file types having text content. Since I can't add all the file extensions that have text content(because there are unlimited amount of them), also for files without any extension users can't open file with my app in the open with menu, I wanted to add desktop extension to handle such thing.

Comment: in my opinion, support all the file type is not good practice, it will make the uwp app complex.

Comment: @CoCalceDew this has been implemented in Windows 10 2004 (build 19041). Check my answer for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 10 2004 (build 19041) microsoft introduced `uap10:FileType` attribute in package manifest and by providing `*` as the value the app is available in open with menu of all types of files even files without any extension. To use this just add the following code to your manifest:

```
xmlns:uap10="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/10"
...
<uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
  <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="anyfile">
    <uap:Logo>Assets\mylogo.png</uap:Logo>
    <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
      <uap:FileType>.txt</uap:FileType>
      <uap10:FileType>*</uap10:FileType>
    </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
  </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
</uap:Extension>
```

This only works for Windows 10 build 19041 and above. The additional `uap:FileType` is necessary if app targets minimum version below 19041 to pass manifest validation, otherwise it can be omitted.

#### Update 1

For Windows 10 version older than build 19041, a desktop component can be provided that uses [`IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateForFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-iapplicationactivationmanager-activateforfile) to redirect file activation to UWP app. The sample code in C++/WinRT looks like this:

```
init_apartment();

LPWSTR* szArglist = NULL;
INT nArgs;
szArglist = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLine(), &nArgs);
if (szArglist && nArgs > 1)
{
    INT ct = nArgs - 1;
    HRESULT hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
    com_ptr<IShellItemArray> ppsia = NULL;
    PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE* rgpidl = new(std::nothrow) PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE[ct];
    if (rgpidl)
    {
        hr = S_OK;
        INT cpidl;
        for (cpidl = 0; SUCCEEDED(hr) && cpidl < ct; cpidl++)
        {
            hr = SHParseDisplayName(szArglist[cpidl + 1], NULL, &rgpidl[cpidl], 0, NULL);
        }

        if (cpidl > 0 && SUCCEEDED(SHCreateShellItemArrayFromIDLists(cpidl, rgpidl, ppsia.put())))
        {
            com_ptr<IApplicationActivationManager> appActivationMgr = NULL;
            if (SUCCEEDED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ApplicationActivationManager, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, __uuidof(appActivationMgr), appActivationMgr.put_void())))
            {
                DWORD pid = 0;
                appActivationMgr->ActivateForFile(AUMID, ppsia.get(), NULL, &pid);
            }
            appActivationMgr.~com_ptr();
        }

        for (INT i = 0; i < cpidl; i++)
        {
            CoTaskMemFree(rgpidl[i]);
        }
    }

    ppsia.~com_ptr();
    delete[] rgpidl;
}

LocalFree(szArglist);
uninit_apartment();
```

Additional advantage of using above method to redirect activation is user can even open restricted file types (i.e. .cmd, .bat etc) with UWP app directly.